# Animation delay in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I'm working with CSS animations. I want the text to come one after another in a loop. I tried but I'm unable to mention proper timings. Div1 is overlapping with all div's. How to adjust the animation timings? I'm ok with using jquery. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be the problem here?

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}

#load {
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;
  height:36px;
  left:50%;
  top:40%;
  margin-left:-400px;
  overflow:visible;
}

#load div {
  position:absolute;
  width:900px;
  opacity:0;
   animation:move 4s linear infinite;
  color:#35C4F0;
}
 #load div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay:8s;
} 
#load div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay:16s;
}
#load div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay:24s;
}


@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
  }
 35% {
  left: 41%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 65% {
  left:59%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
  left:100%; 
  opacity:0;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes move {
 0% {
  left:0; 
  opacity:0;
 }
 35% {
  left:41%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 65% {
  left:59%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
  left:100%; 
  opacity:0;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
 0% {
  left:0; 
  opacity:0;
 }
 35% {
  left:41%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 65% {
  left:59%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
  left:100%;
  opacity:0;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes move {
 0% {
  left:0; 
  opacity:0;
 }
 35% {
  left:41%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 65% {
  left:59%; 
  opacity:1;
 }
 100% {
  left:100%; 
  opacity:0;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="load">
  <div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
  <div>Measure & monitorIt is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable c projects</div>
  <div>Intelligence of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Important note: the delay should never be a multiplier of the duration because after all the delays all the animation will become exactly the same

Comment: @ Temani Afif using jquery if it is possible help me.

Answer (score 0):

I create a very simple loop in jquery. You can change the interval but pay attention to write it bigger than the duration of your animation (in my example it is the same :P).

```js
 var i=1;

    var interval = function () {
        $("div").removeClass("animate")
        $("#load div:nth-child("+i+")").addClass("animate");
        i = ($("#load div").length==i) ? 1 : i+1;
    }

    interval(); /*remove this line if you don't want start immediately */
    setInterval(interval, 4000);
```

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}

#load {
  position:absolute;
  width:600px;
  height:36px;
  left:50%;
  top:40%;
  margin-left:-400px;
  overflow:visible;
}

#load div {
  position:absolute;
  width:900px;
  opacity:0;
  color:#35C4F0;
}

.animate{
  animation:move 4s linear;  
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {
        left:0; 
        opacity:0;
    }
    35% {
        left:41%; 
        opacity:1;
    }
    65% {
        left:59%; 
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%; 
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="load" >
      <div>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
      <div>Measure & monitor It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable c projects</div>
      <div>Intelligence of a page when looking at its layout.</div>
    
    </div>
```